# Can't install tensorflow in python 3.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I've been trying to install tensorflow on windows using pip with `pip install --upgrade tensorflow`and with the url `pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl`

With the plain pip method I get a "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement" and with the url I get the error "tensorflow_gpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

I've installed cuda and I am using python 3.8 64Bits with pip 19.0.3

edit: I've also have installed the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019 thingy

Comment: Can you check the result of `pip --version` and if it coincides with `pip3 --version`

Comment: Can you provide all of the error output?

Comment: pip and pip3 have the same version

Comment: full error log: https://i.gyazo.com/d9929c4acb8d81aaa64eae27fdc6a514.png

Comment: Run `python -c "from pip._internal.pep425tags import get_supported; print(get_supported()[0])"`, what does it print?

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you have posted the correct link for tensorflow, but when you sent the error code that you get while trying to install the wheel it is the wheel for python 3.7 hence the "cp37" when in the link it is "cp38". Verify that you are trying to install the correct file and let me know if there is anything else. Try this url: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Comment: You are now using the wrong url, use this https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.2.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

Comment: Ive used that url. Same output https://gyazo.com/e3561893692c7858861907f611e0f52b

Comment: Have you verified you are using the pip associated with your version of python? Also you can try to run python3 -m pip to try to force usage of the correct pip.